# Dynamically changing content of a post (CMS)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I´m trying to create a simple CMS. Editing posts works fine, but i'm struggling on how i would switch the "current" post which you are editing (Using ajax).

I figured out i could add a extra input-field containing the current post id to each "overview" item (which is hidden using css).

What i'm looking for (or other solution) : If one of the "overview-post-box" is clicked, using jquery/js finds the element with class: "post-id" (in that particular item ofcourse). And sends out a XHR-request to another page containing that ID, this returns the requested post which is placed in the "edit post" fields.

Any ideas on this are welcome! Thanks in advance!

```
<?php foreach($projects as $project){ ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $project['project_link'] ?>" class="overview-post-box">
        <div class="overview-post">
           <div class="post-id"><?php echo $project['project_id']; ?></div>
               <div class="title">
                   <?php echo $project['project_title']; ?>
               </div>
               <div class="content">
                  <?php echo substr($project['project_content'], 0, strpos($project['project_content'], ' ', 40)) ?>
               </div>
        </div>
   </a>
<?php }; ?>
```

[image: The result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to accomplish this task specially VueJs sounds like a winner to do this task but for jQuery i think that you can do something like this.

1. First append to a data attribute the ID of your project

```html
<a data-id="<?php echo $project['project_id']; ?>" href="<?php echo $project['project_link'] ?>" class="overview-post-box">
```

2.- Bind the jQuery handler to get the post data and update your form elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.overview-post-box').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault(); //Stop default <a> behavior 
      var id = $(this).data('id'); //get the current clicked post id
      //do an ajax request to fetch post data
      $.get('/getpostdata.php?id='+id,function(response){
       //return a json from your php side something like
       // {data: { title: 'post title', body: 'post body' }

      /* asign the json values to your inputs */
      $('your_input_class or id to the hidden id').val(id);
      $('your_input_class or id to the title').val(response.data.title);
      $('your_input_class or id to the body').val(response.data.body);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, worked great. I clearly didn't know you can use any of these data attributes, they are quite useful so to see :)

Comment: I'm glad that thing helped you :)